# Windows session unlock by network

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to be able to unlock a windows (7 and greater) locked session by a network message send from my phone, when it's in close range of the pc.
I was looking into a power shell script that can achieve this. The script should be executed when a message is received from the phone.
This is a example that unlocks the machine when you are connected remotely to it:
    tscon $sessionid /dest:console
I don't know if this is possible using a powershell command running from the suspended session.
I also looked into pGina but that doesn't seem like a viable option.
Can anyone lead me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: Well you could use Invoke-Command as long as PS Remoting is enabled but I can't get tscon to connect on a server I've got set up next to me, keeps saying Access Denied. Which part exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Ahhh it was because although it was locked the console was still on that session... blegh. Need to disconnect the session first then reconnect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you can use tscon:

```
tscon $id /DEST:console
```

BUT you CAN'T do this when the console is *connected* AND locked. I guess it's already connected or some nonsense? Idk. You can tell this is the case when you have a "Switch User" button on the Lock screen, and you get an error 7045 or 5 "The requested session access is denied"

Anyway you first need to disconnect the session from the console while keeping it alive. You should be able to achieve this with:

```
tsdiscon $id
```

This will remove the session from the console and allow you to reconnect it, which automatically unlocks it.

So you just have to work out the ID then plug those two lines into an Invoke-Command and you're set. Note if you're invoking with a different username you'll need to specify the password of the session you're connecting.

EDIT: Or alternatively I guess you could use the /SERVER:$host parameter but you will certainly need to include the password in this case unless you're logged in to the same domain user.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. This works if you disconnect the session before and add a timer before you connect.

Comment: Huh, I guess it sends the command and returns before completing. You'll probably want to use a timer in a loop to catch errors if it takes a little longer sometimes.